# which SSDT for VS 2017 when I have SQL Server 2016 DE

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I have VS 2017 CE, SQL Server 2016 DE and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 13.0.16106.4. About VS is showing Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools as installed.

I would like to install SSDT so that I can do the SSRS/SSIS and SSAS but I don't know which one to install, it's giving few options from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt#use-ssdt-in-visual-studio-2017)

It reads

Download SQL Server Data Tools 17.1 for Visual Studio 2015

Download Data-Tier Application Framework (DacFx) 17.1

From the same website

It then advises "To use SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2017 see this section below". When I go to the link provided it takes me to visualstudio.com website. It's not apparent to me what I need to download from there, is it the Community Edition?

Going back to the first link I provided, it advises...
If you are using SSDT with Visual Studio 2017, install the AS and RS components:

Analysis Services

Reporting Services

I also found another link...www.visualstudio.com/vs/ssdt/

Also are there any conflict between sql server 2016 and vs 2017 CE when taking SSRS/SSIS or SSAS tasks?

StackOverFlow is giving me message that I need to have number of reputation before I can give more than 1 website link.

Can someone advise me which one to install?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2017, there is not yet a stand alone install of SSIS|AS|RS. However, there are VSIX installs available for RS and AS. See links below.

SSIS is working on creating a standalone install as well as a VSIX package.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects